# Nginx as Reverse Proxy for Prestashop

Tags: nginx, proxy, prestashop, reverse

I have this scenario with **Nginx** as **reverse proxy** and **Prestashop**:

I have **Prestashop** installed as a **container with Proxmox** and it has been configured with a **local IP address** (192.168.0.10) instead of a domain name. I can access Prestashop via the local IP without problems through the local network.

I have nginx as a reverse proxy installed on another VM that receives the request with a domain name (**subdomain.example.com**) with an SSL certificate on the **Nginx**, and makes a **proxy_pass** for the local IP address (**192.168.0.10**).

When the request is made via the external domain Prestashop redirects [**subdomain.example.com**] to [**192.168.0.1**] which is **not expected**.

With other attempts returns the error (too many redirects) ...
other attempts returns the error 500 ...
I've already tried to enable SSL on prestashop, assign the domain [subdomain.example.com] on prestashop, activate multistore and several other attempts without any success.
I found a tutorial that suggest do edit de [**Link.php**] file on Prestashop but don't work for me too.
I can't find any material on the web that solves this problem, nor in the Prestashop documentation, so I ask for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a misconfiguration in Prestashop as your webserver config is pretty straightforward.

Please make sure :

- that your DB table **ps_shop_url** is containing the correct **subdomain.example.com** in domain and domain_ssl row.
- that *.htaccess* file in Prestashop in root folder is not containing references to your backend IP (192.168.0.1) - If this is the case, you'll need to regenerate in from backoffice (click SAVE in Seo&URL tab )

Comment: Tks for your response. I will test it and give you a feedback.